# How to blur the edges of bitmap to fit the square like blur square or iphone inbuilt feature

Tags: java, android, image-manipulation, blur

I want to implement the type of blurring shown in the picture below. I have my bitmap, and I want to implement this blurring on the sides of to make it a square like iPhone's inbuilt feature to fit WhatsApp or Instagram display picture. Till now I have been able to fill color in those edges using `Color.Blue` etc.

For more info: [How to create a square bitmap from a rectangular bitmap in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744120/how-to-create-a-square-bitmap-from-a-rectangular-bitmap-in-android)

I want to fill those white sides in that question's image with blurred part.

[image: Blur]

Comment: This is nothing but: a blur on the full image, then an overlay of the unblurred but cropped version (in height) is added to it.

Comment: `Divide et impera` should be a concept familiar to every developer. In a few words, every problem can be turned into smaller ones. Find a fast blur tutorial, a crop tutorial and an image overlay tutorial. put them together and you're done.

Comment: Hi, i tried to do it, i have a blurred image and an empty bitmap square, and i fill the rectangle or original image in that and those sides are left.Can you help me in picking those pixels from edges of blurred image using getPixel(x,y) method. only the side pixels with dmesnions (width+height/2)

Comment: ... Which is not the right approach. Re-read my previous comment carefully.

Comment: the problem i am facing with the method is that say i have a bitmap with dimen 700*1400. i create the new one as i need a square of dimen 1400*1400, how will i overlay those 350 pixels on both sides which don't exist in blurred image as the blurred bitmap is also of 700*1400 will only overlay 700*1400 part not extra 350

Comment: **1** - Blur the original (copy). **2** - Crop the original (copy). **3** - Overlay the cropped image (centering it) over the blurred image. `I gave you the algorithm - now you write the code`.

Comment: that is the problem sir, i don't want to crop the image i am building it to use full image without cropping any part of it.just like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744120/how-to-create-a-square-bitmap-from-a-rectangular-bitmap-in-android

Comment: Then just use 2 versions of the same image. One bigger and one smaller. The bigger one is blurred. That's really it. You can overlay the images and set the result in an ImageView OR use 2 ImageViews in a RelativeLayout.

Comment: @DeepinderBains if you actually look at the picture you posted you can clearly tell there are 2 images being used here as the blurred portions do not line up with the image

Answer (score 0):

Its the blurred version of same image shown in the background. Following code gives you a blurred effect of same image. Adjust BLUR_RADIUS for amplitude of effect.

```
public class BlurBuilder {
    private static final float BITMAP_SCALE = 0.4f;
    private static final float BLUR_RADIUS = 20f;

    public static Bitmap blur(Context context, Bitmap image) {
        int width = Math.round(image.getWidth() * BITMAP_SCALE);
        int height = Math.round(image.getHeight() * BITMAP_SCALE);

        Bitmap inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);
        Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);

        RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
        ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
        Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
        Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap);
        theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
        theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
        theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
        tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);

        return outputBitmap;
    }
}
```

[Source](https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-blur-images-efficiently-with-androids-renderscript)